# left allign formula MathJax

Tags: html, alignment, latex, mathjax, reveal.js

I'm creating a presentation with [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js)

To show some math stuff I use the builtin plugin for MathJax (thin MathJax wrapper).
It works fine so far except for one thing:

I'm struggeling to left allign one of my math formulas.
I want it to be like this:

```
                               a^2 + b^2 = c^2 (centered text)
a: in CM (left alligned text)
b: in CM (left alligned text)
c: in CM (left alligned text)
```

At the moment everything is centered.

```
                               a^2 + b^2 = c^2 (centered text)
                               a: in CM (centered text)
                               b: in CM (centered text)
                               c: in CM (centered text)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use the `multline` environment and `\shoveleft` to left align the equations to the left.  Unfortunately, the default is to use only 85% of the container for `multline` environments, but perhaps that is good enough.

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML'></script>

\begin{multline}
\shoveleft a\\
\shoveleft b\\
\shoveleft c
\end{multline}
```

Otherwise, if that is not far enough to the left, you could use a container with negative left margin CSS to shift the math further to the left.